# Fast single table database

Tags: sql, database, caching, indexing, nosql

I have an analytics database where I make complex queries. Each of these queries generates thousands of rows. I want to store these results in some kind of on disk cache so I can get the results later on. I can't insert the results back into the database where the results came from as that database is read only. The requirements of this cache are.

- Very very fast to insert rows. MySQL is a non-starter.
- Fast to filter and sort the results
- No multi-table joins required
- No transactions

I'm interested to hear of any SQL or NoSQL solutions that can help with this.

Comment: MySQL has different engine types - Memory would be fast, but won't be persisted if the system turns off IIRC.

Comment: Have you tried MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE statement or the multi-row version of INSERT? They are both much faster than using one INSERT per row.

Comment: SQLite3 you should take a look at. /Yoda

Comment: I am actually using the MySQL multi-row version of insert but I run into a problem where there is a limit on the number variables I can bind to the query. I guess I could avoid binding and generate the pure SQL and create a larger query.

Comment: Where did you encounter this limit ( in the programming language?), and how many variables are you binding? My 'normalization' sense is tingling.

Comment: Off the top of my head i can't remember exactly but I'm sure it was at the lower level of the MySQL driver and not the language. I did a binary search for the point where it would die. It's in the order of several hundred at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably take a look at NoSQL solutions. Maybe Cassandra, http://cassandra.apache.org/ which is used by facebook and digg among others

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at SQLite? It's used by apps ( i.e. Thunderbird, FF ) when they need query power, but not a full-fledged relational database, amongst other uses.

Comment: SQLite only provides a single insert command and thus is somewhat worse than MySQL which provides a multi-row insert command.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the platform, but on Windows you can use the built-in [Esent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2008/10/23/esent-extensible-storage-engine-api-in-the-windows-sdk.aspx) database engine. It would provide data persistence with sorting and high performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of RAM, might want to try the SQLite in-memory database: http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

With less RAM, try SQLite temporary databases (further down the page - see hyperlink above). These also use the in-memory cache but parts might be flushed to disk if the database becomes large.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at Advantage database. The local server is free and it supports both SQL and non-SQL solutions. The non-SQL solution will certainly be faster than the SQL approach. The table can be designated as cached so it will stay in memory as long as possible for fast insertion. [Advantage Database Server](http://www.advantagedatabase.com)